# How to use UPS with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: power-management, battery, ups

Hello I have a UPS but can not see what procedure the battery and how to remain percent spending. Here I attach some photos looks like the battery of Ubuntu 14.04

[image]

The battery once it exists, and then disappears and then appears again.
Here's how it looks and statistics Power Statistics.
[image]

how I wanted to run this UPS to see normal battery, but not red and blinking so. Model and brand are the following

EATON 5E 850V/480W.

Comment: The battery is not exhausted before a minute of Windows has been around 56-57% .

Comment: Is the UPS from APC? Try installing `apcupsd`: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/apcupsd

Comment: @muru What is APC some company? If so not is not of APC.